# Does my cat have eye worms?

Tags: cats, parasites, eye-disease

I managed to pull 5-6 strange elastic white-translucent *organisms* from Toby's eyes. I never witnessed them move.

They're definitely not hairs, and using 19x macro lens I took some pictures of them, improvising a home-made microscope.

Afterwards, I took him to the vet, where we managed to pull one more worm (?) from the eye and vet examined it using his microscope. He seemed confused and unsure. I am from Europe and the only parasite here that infests cats' eyes is *Thelazia callipaeda*, so we assumed it should be it, although the vet admitted he couldn't identify body parts (morphology or whatever), and neither was moving. I also failed to find similarity between verified (source used: [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/)) microscopic images of *T. callipaeda* and my own kinda-microscopic images.

Anyway, we decided to move forward with Milbemax.

Can somebody please help confirm that this might be indeed *T. callipaeda*, or at least if it is in fact a parasite, based on the pictures I took?

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: These are the sort of things that you should consult a vet for. You've clearly done your homework, but unless an actual vet posts here, we're not going to be able to do much other than compare your images to other internet images.

Comment: @Flater the OP indicates a visit to the vet in his question.  Also we do have Vets and Vet techs who frequently post answers here.

Comment: I googled "eye worms", now i'm having nightmares for a month

Answer (score 2):

First, please clean your cat's eye to prevent further infection. Next, comfort your cat and very lastly after making a comfy travel crate with cushions and some course of water to keep from hitting eye, and staying hydrated to fight whatever infection the cat has. Take the cat to get a second opinion like you would for a child.

Answer (score 1):

[Removal of *Loa loa*](https://youtu.be/nkEkDHOQTLs).

This clip shows the removal of *Loa loa* from a human eye. The description in the video gives much detail. It’s possible this is what has affected your cat. A veterinarian visit is a must.